# crond service not working inside docker container [image: amazon linux 2]

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-linux-2

we can install cron service using below command in container

```
yum install crontabs

or
yum -y install cronie
```

service can start using : `crond`

I have configured the cron in `/etc/crontab`, but it is not working.

And not generating cron log file also,

any suggestion on this issue?
will crond service will work inside docker container ?

Comment: Can you show dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

A docker container does not have a deamonizing service manager. If you install crond inside a container, it will never be triggered as it is not started.

You should read more about the notion of services in Docker. For starter : https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Here is an example of cronlike in Docker: https://blog.knoldus.com/running-a-cron-job-in-docker-container/